# How can I add these locations on the map from JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

My project runs and it show already current location of device. My question is there is a `JSON` that include 4 address. I should add these addresses on the map. How can add these locations to map from `JSON`?

Website of this JSON: https://instalyticsdbplandiag814.blob.core.windows.net/mobiversite/location.json

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(jsonAsString);

        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("locations");

        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

            JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String name=item.getString("name");

            String lattitude= item.getString("lattitude");

            String longitude= item.getString("longitude");


            //process as you want
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: that is itself whole another topic. to make things simple, you may add this json to your android assets folder copying from the url

Comment: Ok. Thabks for your help.